# Encryption hmac result is shorter in C than C#

Tags: c, hmac, sha256

Sometimes you have to implement C-Code and Encryption so I have a Problem with my C-Code implementation of hmac256 or sha2_hmac Implementation:

```
unsigned char key[19] = { "abcdef" };
size_t keylen = 18;
unsigned char input[64] = {"123456789"}; 
size_t ilen = 63;         
unsigned char output[32];
int is224 = 0;


sha2_hmac(key, keylen, input, ilen, output, is224);

char result[64] = {};
char result2[64] = {};

for(int j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
        sprintf(result, "%X", output[j]);
        strcat(result2, result);
}
```

But the result is too short, when I compare it to the C# Code.

Comment: Please post the expected output, the actual output, and the C# code.

Comment: Quiz question: Does `sprintf(result, "%X", output[j]);` give the desired result if `output[j]` < 16? If not, what could be changed on the format string to achieve it?

Comment: sorry do not understand...the result was too short not too long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to adjust your `sprintf()` function call like this:

```
sprintf(result, "%02X", output[j]);
```